# How to copy installed apps along with data to other mobile using sdcard?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Suppose I've installed five apps in some mobile. I used them for few days, I would like to copy them to another mobile along with data using sdcard. Means in whatever mobile I put that sdcard, my all apps with the data should work fine. It's like cloning windows os and installing same state os to other, but only a selected apps in my scenario. Is it possible? Ask me you did not get question? Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is mainly for programming related questions. Your questions seem to better fit here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Depending. If the apps support it, it might work out of the box with Google Play. If not, you might have to do it manually or with specialized apps for that. But that would work only if you have root for your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of you question is not about programing, your goal can be archived using `adb` tool from Android SDK.

Connect your first device to PC and use `adb backup -apk -shared $package_name` to create application backup file on your PC.

Then connect second device to PC and use `adb restore` to install the app.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey but I want a feasible a solution to copy over a mass scale like.. 100's of mobiles with some solution like.. sdcards or some network download

Comment: you can script all those manipulations - and only change devices on the USB-cable. Or use adb-over-WiFi (but it takes more time to setup it on a device)